# Pidgin cannot connect to jabber.org - SSL error

Tags: ssl, pidgin, jabber, xmpp

I normally use Pidgin (2.6.4 and now 2.6.5) on Ubuntu to connect to jabber.org via XMPP for instant messaging.  Yesterday, sometimes when I tried to connect, I would get the following error:

```
Unable to validate certificate

The certificate for jabber.org could not be validated.
The certificate chain presented is invalid.
```

I have no idea why this is happening; other people in the same office are having no problem connecting to jabber.org, and today it's happening every time. I tried removing the certificate for jabber.org (in ~/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers/jabber.org), and restarting Pidgin a few times, but no dice. I've tried every combination of settings I can think of (turning off TLS/SSL, allowing unencrypted streams, etc.) but nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the jabber.org site, they are doing major changes and problems are to be expected for a few days. I have the same problems, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ran Pidgin on another machine, got the new current certificate, and copied it over to the old machine, and now I can connect.  Still don't know why Pidgin wasn't able to notice that the old certificate was missing after I deleted it.